Ширина блока по ширине контента


.mmm {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content max-content;
  gap: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  container-type: size;
  fill: #fff;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 20%;
  padding: 8px;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .9);
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 136cqh;
}

.mmm svg {height: 100%}
.mmm  div {
  font-size: 45cqb;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="mmm">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
      <path d="M35.716 31.884a1.349 1.349 0 0 1-1.895.23L.517 6.011a1.35 1.35 0 1 1 1.667-2.125l33.252 26.05c.635.512.742 1.362.28 1.947z" fill="red"></path>
      <path d="M3.6 15.3v5.4c0 1.492 1.21 2.65 2.7 2.65h4.717l7.589 6.745a1.63 1.63 0 0 0 1.196.506c.25 0 .504-.052.74-.16.65-.29 1.06-.931 1.06-1.64v-2.832L4.993 12.954c-.827.461-1.392 1.283-1.392 2.346zm16.945-9.741a1.803 1.803 0 0 0-1.937.296l-6.519 5.794 9.513 7.46V7.198c0-.708-.41-1.4-1.057-1.64zm6.266 8.273a1.35 1.35 0 0 0-1.708 2.092 2.69 2.69 0 0 1 1 2.076 2.68 2.68 0 0 1-1.002 2.075 1.35 1.35 0 0 0-.44 1.428l1.21.95c.029.001.055.018.084.018.3 0 .604-.1.854-.304A5.37 5.37 0 0 0 28.803 18c0-1.614-.726-3.128-1.992-4.168zm3.404-4.158a1.35 1.35 0 1 0-1.712 2.088c1.909 1.563 3 3.836 3 6.238 0 2.402-1.094 4.674-2.999 6.239-.059.048-.09.114-.138.17l2.126 1.666c2.355-2.067 3.711-4.987 3.711-8.075 0-3.212-1.451-6.25-3.988-8.326z"></path>
   </svg>
   <div class="title">Включить звук</div>
</div>



Как сделать так, чтобы ширина блока была по ширине контента?

Строчка с текстом может быть больше, может меньше. Как сделать, чтобы ширина блока подстраивалась под текст?

А не проще запихать текст в тот же SVG?

Текстовая строчка может быть длине, может короче... Через html по мне как практичнее...

Сделайте display: inline-grid; для грида, уберите container-type: size; и width: 136cqh;

container-type: size; необходим, иначе размер шрифта не будет меняться пропорционально высоте родителя.
